# how to access my Android phone from my terminal?

Tags: command-line, android

I plugged my Kit-kat android phone up to my Ubuntu 14.04 computer and I enter the terminal and I want to be able to access files on my phone like the media and music folders through the terminal... is this possible?

Comment: Depends on the vendor. Some (Samsung) make it harder, others easier.

Comment: I have the note 4 @mikewhatever

Comment: ...and what happens when you connect it? Does Ubuntu see it? What's the output of `dmesg`? Is there an option is the phone settings to allow connecting to USB?

Answer (score 29):

Android devices usually uses the ***Media Transfer Protocol*** (MTP) when connecting via the USB. This protocol works differently than the traditional USB.

Simply put, this is a way to ensure that the phone does not share too much data with the computer. The computer makes a query, and the phone answers it. The phone may decide to share the file or ignore  the query. Similarly, when the computer deletes a file, the phone has the ability to decide whether to actually delete the file or not.

Okay, enough introduction. To access a device connected via MTP, you need the information about it's #Bus and #Dev. To do so, you can run the following command.

`usb-devices`

This will provide you with a list of connected usb-devices. You need to find your device from this list. It can be a bit tiring, so you can search for the device with the available **Manufacturer** option. Simply use the following command.

```
usb-devices  | grep "Manufacturer=OnePlus" -B 3
```

This will provide you with 4 lines of information, where the firs line is as follows.

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 13 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
```

As you can see here, the associated Bus is 02, and Dev is 13.

Now change your directory to /run/user/1000/gvfs/ and see the list of folders there.

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/
ls
```

You will find the associated MTP device with the #Bus and #Dev in the list. For example, mine was ***mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C013%5D***. Now simply change your directory using the following command.

```
cd mtp\:host\=%5Busb%3A002%2C013%5D/
```

***Voila***!
You are inside the file storage!

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm, thx

Comment: Worked like a charm, but it wasn't mpt:host, it was gphoto2:host

Comment: What if there is nothing in `/run/user/1000/gvfs/`. My `ls` doesn't show anything.

Comment: same here. the folder is empty. i set my phone to 'file transfer' mode in case that matters.

Comment: Note the following command.

`usb-devices  | grep "Manufacturer=OnePlus" -B 3`

I used OnePlus because my phone was manufactured by OnePlus. You will have to put your manufacturer name In it's place. I think this should fix the error.

Comment: If the folder /run/user/1000/gvfs/ s empty, install gvfs-fuse with "sudo apt-get install gvfs-fuse" and reboot your system. Probably will work after that. =)

Answer (score 18):

You can find the mount point under the `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs` directory. The main directory may be something like `mtp:host=…` with some escaped characters and USB vendor/product IDs, but you should be able to access your files from in there in a terminal.

Comment: I'm uncertain how to follow your instructions. What directory is `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs` in? I can't find it anywhere. Is it hidden?

Comment: The `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` defaults to `/run/user/$UID/` I think. There is a `gvfs` sub-directory within it.

Comment: I've found the `gvfs directory, but I don't see anything in it using the `ls` command.

Comment: OK. This was working when I answered the question in 2015 on 14.04. Maybe something changed/broke in newer Ubuntu in relation to this?

Comment: Possibly, should I re-ask the question, bu with it related to modern systems?

Comment: Maybe should file a bug report on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs