# How to scan internal memory of my Android phone around a certain index entry in order to find lost utf-8/LF (for Linux/Adroid) text?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, android, phone, utf-8

Last night, I was using the [Jota Text Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sblo.pandora.jota&hl=en) app on my LG G3 Anroid phone running [Fulmics](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/development/rom-fulmics-rom-3-0-tweaks-hub-ota-v30b-t3304556). The phone (which I am planning to replace very soon) crashed about two times whilst I was writing a text with the help of this editor. After the last crash, I wanted to open the TXT file I just edited, but it was displayed as empty by the editor. So, the index entry still seems to be there but the text cannot be found anymore. Thus, I would like to scan an interval of about [-1 MiB, +1 MiB] around that index entry in order to find the lost utf-8/LF (for Linux/Adroid) text.

I suppose that this could be done via the terminal, but I have troubles [finding the right path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596441/how-to-access-my-android-phone-from-my-terminal) in order to access my phone via the terminal itself. Also, I have not found out what file system the internal memory of my Android phone uses. Do you know where I can figure this out?

**Edit:** I have found a way to access my phone via the terminal. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/585675/845469) has helped my a lot.

Furthermore, I was able to access the folder with Nautilus. There, I can see two versions of my TXT file. The first one is called `text.txt`, has a size of `0 Bytes` and has been edited at `00:55 hrs (12:55 a.m.)`. Below, there is an entry called `text.txt~` which has a size of `78.0 kB` and has been edited at `00:55 hrs (12:55 a.m.)`. But I cannot open `text.txt~` with *gedit*, and opening `text.txt` will just show me an empty document, just as it is displayed on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

the solution to your problem is:

```
cd szTheCorrectDirectoryName
cp text.txt~ text.txt
```

which will restore the backup of the text file.

You can do the same in Nautilus as well: rename the existing `text.txt` to `text.new` and then rename `text.txt~` to `text.txt`

#### If that doesn't work, your text file is lost, Sorry!

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the two solutions has worked. Trying to restore the backup of the text file resulted in a new text file with `0 Bytes` which, of course, contained nothing. Renaming also did not work. Opening `text.txt`, which was `text.txt~` before, also delivers an empty document – no matter whether it is opened with *gedit* or *Jota Text Editor*.