# All sound files on Samsung Android phone are missing when trying to view them in my folder

Tags: files, filesystem, android, filemanager, samsung

My voice recordings on my Samsung Android phone are usually stored in the folder /sounds/ but even though on my phone I see 20 recordings, the file explorer app on my Ubuntu 16.04 is showing this folder as being empty.

I'm able to find all my photograph files easily in the /DCIM/ folder, but the /sounds/ folder looks empty! Then I went to the /Music/ folder and again all the sound files are gone! I have the folders for several albums, and in each album there's supposed to be a few mp3 files and an album image, but only the album image is visible in the folder!

So I tried the command line. I used this: [how to access my Android phone from my terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596441/how-to-access-my-android-phone-from-my-terminal). It worked like a charm to get into the android phone folder. But then I ran "cd Sounds" then "ls", and I got nothing, even though on the phone itself I can see 20 recordings!

I have tried to view hidden files using, for example CTRL+H. The folders still seem to be empty.

How can I view these files in Ubuntu? 
I know it's good practice to also give the phone model but unfortunately it's an inherited phone and I don't know it!

UPDATE: I tried on a completely different computer, which is also Ubuntu 16.04. Again, the sound files cannot be viewed in Ubuntu. However on both the old computer and the new computer, when I plug the phone into the USB port, there is a window that pops up which says "Shotwell". This is new and was not there before when I could view the files. Perhaps there was an Ubuntu update which installed this? I un-installed Shotwell, but the files are still missing and the Shotwell program still opens when I plug my USB in (as if Shotwell just keeps coming back again).

Comment: Do you have an SD card in your phone? Any chance it's a just problem with accessing the wrong drive?

Comment: I do not have an SD card. Even if I did this doesn't make sense, because the album photo in my folder for a music album, is showing up on Ubuntu when I open the folder, but not any sound files.